# How do i create a fluent Nhibernate mapping having join of multiple tables but select only selective colums from each table?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have four tables in database like

**tableAnnual**
primary - Key creationDate DATETIME,
primary - Key Id INTEGER,
column AnnualAmount,
column AnnualCurrency,
column Column3,
column Column4,
column Column5,
column Column6

**tableMonthly**
primary - Key creationDate DATETIME,
primary - Key Id INTEGER,
column MonthlyAmount,
column MonthlyCurrency,
column Column31,
column Column41,
column Column51,

**tableSharevalue**
primary - Key creationDate DATETIME,
column AverageSharevalueAmount,
column CurrentSharevalue,

**tableMiscDetails**
primary - Key creationDate DATETIME,
column clientType,
column clientName,
column MarketValueAmount,
column clientAddress,

I want to join all the four tables and get only few columns from each table like AnnualAmount and AnnualCurrency from tableAnnual, MonthlyAmount and
MonthlyCurrency from tableMonthly, CurrentSharevalue from tableSharevalue and MarketValueAmount from tableMiscDetails on "creationDate" WHERE Id = "XXXXXXX"

I have defined the entity class in C# code as follows, based on the required columns from all four tables

```
public class ShareDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string AnnualAmount { get; set; }
    public string AnnualCurrency { get; set; }
    public string MonthlyAmount { get; set; }
    public string MonthlyCurrency { get; set; }
    public string CurrentSharevalue { get; set; }
    public string MarketValueAmount { get; set; }
}

How do I achieve the Mapping in Fluent Nhibernate ?

public class ShareDetailsMap : ClassMap<ShareDetails>
{

}
```

Please note that i only need few columns from each table.Also, Is the entity class that I have created is okay or do i need to change its structure as well?

All I need to do is to have the following query executed through QueryOver, JoinAlias

Select tableAnnual.AnnualAmount, tableAnnual.AnnualCurrency, 
tableMonthly.MonthlyAmount, MonthlyAmount.MonthlyCurrency,
tableSharevalue.CurrentSharevalue, tableMiscDetails.clientType, tableMiscDetails.clientName, tableMiscDetails.MarketValueAmount
from tableAnnual
outer join tableMonthly on tableAnnual.creationDate  = tableMonthly.creationDate
outer join tableSharevalue on tableMonthly.creationDate = tableSharevalue.creationDate
outer join tableMiscDetails on tableSharevalue.creationDate = tableMiscDetails.creationDate
Where id = '123456'

Comment: I think you can accomplish this using Join in your mapping. You can also use QueryOver with JoinAlias and SelectList.

Comment: When I use Join in mapping class, I am getting all the columns from first table which is of no use unfortunately

Comment: Actually these four tables are pretty much not related, so i am not sure how would i use QueryOver. Any Suggestions ?

Comment: I actually worked up an answer for you using QueryOver, but ended up deleting it. I realized that without a table/view that unites your four tables, my answer didn't make sense.

Comment: No problem mate!!! Now that you're on board, any suggestions :) ?  Because actually if you see column creationDate is common across all tables. I just require to fetch selective columns from these tables

Comment: I will undelete my answer so that you can see it. I'm not sure that the ShareDetails mapping is correct, but I think the overall approach is, if you want to use QueryOver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out the solution myself. Following are the details.

Supposingly, I have entities and mappings for each database table. In one of the entities lets say AnnualInformation entity (tableAnnual).

I will create relationships of MonthlyInformation entity (tableMonthly), ShareValueInformation entity (tableSharevalue) and MiscDetails entity (tableMiscDetails).

The code of AnnualInformation entity will look Like below :

```
public class AnnualInformation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal AnnualAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual string AnnualCurrency { get; set; }
    public virtual MonthlyInformation MonthlyInformation { get; set; }
    public virtual ShareValueInformation ShareValueInformation { get; set; }
    public virtual MiscDetails MiscDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The corresponding mapping class will be as follows:

```
public class AnnualInformationMap : ClassMap<AnnualInformation>
{
    public AnnualInformationMap()
    {
        Table("tableAnnual");
        Id(x => x.CreationDate, "creationDate ");
        Map(x => x.Id, "Id");
        Map(x => x.AnnualAmount, "AnnualAmount");
        Map(x => x.AnnualCurrency, "AnnualCurrency");
        References(x => x.MonthlyInformation).Column("creationDate");
        References(x => x.ShareValueInformation).Column("creationDate");
        References(x => x.MiscDetails).Column("creationDate");
    }
}
```

Now, we need to retrieve the data from all these four database tables with Left Outer Join. Therefore we will work the solution as follows

```
MonthlyInformation monthlyAlias = null;
ShareValueInformation shareAlias = null;
MiscDetails miscAlias = null;

// Create your db session...
using (session)
{
var result = session.QueryOver<AnnualInformation>()
             .JoinAlias(a => a.MonthlyInformation, () => monthlyAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
             .JoinAlias(a => a.ShareValueInformation, () => shareAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
             .JoinAlias(a => a.MiscDetails, () => miscAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
             .SelectList(list => list
                         .Select(x => x.Id)
                         .Select(x => x.CreationDate)
                         .Select(x => x.AnnualAmount)
                         .Select(x => x.AnnualCurrency)
                         .Select(() => monthlyAlias.MonthlyAmount)
                         .Select(() => monthlyAlias.MonthlyCurrency)
                         .Select(() => shareAlias.CurrentSharevalue)
                         .Select(() => miscAlias.MarketValueAmount)
                         ).Where(a => a.Id == 123456).List<object[]>();
}
```

Here it is, the data that we were looking forward to is now a list of object stored in variable result, for completely unrelated entities. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have classes and mappings for your four tables, this might work for you. As said in the comment above, I'm not 100% sure about the ShareDetails mapping below, since it does not connect to an actual db table.

ShareDetails class:

```
public class ShareDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public Annual Annual { get; set; }
    public Monthly Monthly { get; set; }
    public ShareValue ShareValue { get; set; }
    public MiscDetails MiscDetails { get; set; }
}
```

ShareDetails mapping:

```
public class ShareDetailsMap : ClassMap<ShareDetails>
    public ShareDetailsMap(){
        LazyLoad();
        //Don't think you need these since this isn't a db table
        //Id(x => x.DocumentId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("id");
        //Map(x => x.CreationDate).Column("creation_date");
        References(x => x.Annual).Column("creation_date");
        References(x => x.Monthly).Column("creation_date");
        References(x => x.ShareValue).Column("creation_date");
        References(x => x.MiscDetails).Column("creation_date");
    }
}
```

Query that pulls all the random properties into one array of objects:

```
Annual annualAlias = null;
Monthly monthlyAlias = null;
ShareValue shareAlias = null;
MiscDetails miscAlias = null;

// Create your db session...
using (session)
{
    return session.QueryOver<ShareDetails>()
        .JoinAlias(a => a.Annual, () => annualAlias)
        .JoinAlias(a => a.Monthly, () => monthlyAlias)
        .JoinAlias(a => a.ShareValue, () => shareAlias)
        .JoinAlias(a => a.MiscDetails, () => miscAlias)
        .SelectList(list => list
            .Select(() => annualAlias.AnnualAmount)
            .Select(() => annualAlias.AnnualCurrency)
            .Select(() => monthlyAlias.MonthlyAmount)
            .Select(() => monthlyAlias.MonthlyCurrency)
            .Select(() => shareAlias.CurrentShareValue)
            .Select(() => miscAlias.MarkeyValueAmount)
        ).List<object[]>();
}
```

[Good reference on QueryOver](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/03/22/queryover-series-part-3-selecting-and-transforming/)

Comment: Thanks for the code wooters!!! when i implemented your solution I was getting an error that i need to map Id column for ShareDetailsMap class. When i mention the Id column as creation_date, I am getting error like Foreigh Key ShareDetails [creation_date] must have same number of columns as he referenced primary key in Annual

Comment: Select tableAnnual.AnnualAmount, tableAnnual.AnnualCurrency,  
 tableMonthly.MonthlyAmount, MonthlyAmount.MonthlyCurrency,   
tableSharevalue.CurrentSharevalue, tableMiscDetails.clientType,   
tableMiscDetails.clientName, tableMiscDetails.MarketValueAmount from   
tableAnnual outer join tableMonthly on tableAnnual.creationDate =   
tableMonthly.creationDate outer join tableSharevalue on   
tableMonthly.creationDate = tableSharevalue.creationDate outer join   
tableMiscDetails on tableSharevalue.creationDate =   
tableMiscDetails.creationDate Where id = '123456'

Comment: All I need to do is to have the above query executed through QueryOver, JoinAlias

Comment: I figured that Id area of the ShareDetails mapping would give you trouble! I am not sure where to go from here. Hopefully someone else will provide an answer, though I am not holding my breath.